# Weight matrices in transformers

Tags: sequence-to-sequence, bert, machine-translation, transformer, attention-mechanism

I am trying to understand the transformer architecture.

I am aware that the encoder/decoder contains multiple stacked self attention layers. Further each layer contains multiple heads. For example take 8 heads.

Now for a particular layer we will have 8 **different** sets of (Wq, Wk, Wv), the weight matrices used to calculate the query, key and value.

Now what I want to know is whether these weight matrices are **shared** between the different layers i.e are the (Wq, Wk, Wv) matrices of head#1 in layer 1 same for head#1 of layers 2, 3, ....?

And if they are shared, doesn't it affect in parallelization?

Comment: The heads are not shared among layers.

Comment: If with layer 1, you mean the first encoder stack, well Bert uses different sets of Wq, Wk, Wv, but Albert uses the same, so I think it is something that you choose.